# Should I write an email to my potential supervisor before interviewing?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, interview

I've just got into the interview selection of PhD funded program. As I failed another university interview just a week ago, I am quite apprehensive about this upcoming one. As I've read about interviewing tips somewhere, some mentioned emailing potential supervisor and ask for advice for the imminent interview. Should I do this?

Comment: Yes, but do take time to read several papers published by your potential supervisor before writing that email. If the PhD is computer science related, also have a look at [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If there are things you genuinely need to know (How long will the interview last? Do they want you to give a presentation? What sort of questions can you expect?) then an email query is sensible and should be well received. This may be particularly important if you're moving institutions/countries so norms will be different. But don't send an email for the sake of sending an email.

Comment: Thank you so much  for replying to my concern as it has been bugging me lately. As long as it relate to queries concerning the interview, do you reckon with would be reasonable. As my last interview, I found it was strange to see my potential supervisor didn't ask me much questions revolving around my project even though it is a funded project. I had the feeling she didn't like me much because the feedback demonstrate that my research ideas were not coherent enough